# C#: Resolving multiple assemblies using the AssemblyResolve function

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I'm attempting to make a single EXE app. To that end, I have two DLLs that are tagged as embedded resouces in my app. I can successfully use the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(myresolve)` method to return an assembly when the event fires.

The difficulty that I'm running into is that the methods within my application reference multiple assemblies. When I use the above event handler to load and return my assembly, my application looks for a method in the wrong assembly file, and I get a "type load exception".

Therefore, how can I load my assemblies so that my application looks in the proper places for any methods I might use?

Kind regards.

Code Sample:

DLL Resolution:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new  ResolveEventHandler(ResolveDll)

        static Assembly ResolveDll(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApplication.Resources.MyDll1.dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData); //Obviously resolves the first DLL, but how can I also resolve the second?
            }
        }

void SomeMethod()
 {
  MyDll1.Class.CallAMethod()
  MyDll2.Class.CallAnotherMethod() //Type Load exception - Assembly Resolution told it to look in MyDll1.
 }
```

Comment: Please include a minimum, reproducible code sample.

Comment: Have  you tried to use `args.Name`?

Comment: I have not. Could you please provide a short example of what you were thinking?

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion of L.B., I tried a simple If/then block using `args.name`. This has done the trick.

```
if (args.Name == "MyDll1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApplication.Resources.MyDLL1.dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }

        }
        else if (args.Name == "MyDll2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
        {
            using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyApplication.Resources.MyDll2.dll"))
            {
                byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        }
```